# In Python, When yield cost over the return an list?

Tags: python

In many case, people all ways say "use the `yield` to lazily create element."
but I think everything have cost, include the `yield` and its iterator.

In effective nord eyes, I think it's nice question.
so,for example, when I get an function.

```
def list_gen(n):
    if n > MAGIC_NUM:
        return xrange(n)
    else:
        return range(n)
```

How much dose the MAGIC_NUM is?

**UPDATE** sorry for this mistake, I'm origin meaning is compare the iterator's cost and list cost.

**UPDATE AGAIN** Please imaging an case. Whether have an condition, that the memory so limit that it's can't create an iterator.

ha, this question is more funny now.
**UPDATE AGAIN** Why does create an iterator and save the yield context are less then create a list? or How much does iterator cost ?(sorry for my insult) How many bytes?

Comment: You mean `return xrange(n)` or `return range(n)` right?

Comment: @Kos Yeah, I'm fix this mistake.

Comment: Generators use less memory than lists. Hence, if memory is so limited that it can't create an iterator, then it can't create the list either.

Comment: Your last question is really a quite different question from the others, and doesn't really fit stackoverflow, as stackoverflow doesn't really go for "Why" questions. But the yield context is just a stack level. It's not resource intensive, as compared to creating a list that contains a bunch of objects. Even an integer is 12 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing several things up.

```
def list_gen(n):
    i=0
    while i<n:
        yield i
        i += 1
```

This function is a **generator**. Calling it returns a generator object, which is an **iterator**.

An iterator is a thing that has `next()`, i.e. it can be traversed over once. An iterator is created over something using `iter` whenever you do a `for i in something`.

```
def list_gen(n):
    return range(n)

def list_gen(n):
    return xrange(n)
```

These functions are regular functions. One returns a `list` and the other returns an `xrange` object. Both lists and xranges are **iterable**, i.e. multiple independent iterators can be created for them.

---

So back to your question: You're asking whether to return a `list` or an `xrange` object.

That depends, obviously! It depends on what you want to do with the result.

- If you want to mutate it somehow, then you need a real list. Use `range` directly.
- If you only want to iterate over it, then it doesn't make a difference semantically: both an `xrange` object and a `list` returned by `range` will produce an iterator which iterates over the same sequence.

  However, if you use `xrange`, you'll never create the whole list in memory. Why create a full-fledged `list` object in memory if all you want to do is a simple iteration? You don't need to allocate a temporary large memory buffer whenever you want a `for` loop, right?

**Hence: It's safe to stick with `xrange`, since the caller can always make a `list` out of it.**

---

Let's confirm that with a benchmark. We want to know if it's faster to iterate over xranges than over lists constructed by `range` (including the cost of `range` call, of course).

Code:

```
import timeit

ns = [1,2,3, 5, 10, 50, 100]
print 'n', '\t', 'range', '\t', 'xrange'
for n in ns:
    t1 = timeit.timeit("for i in range({}): pass".format(n))
    t2 = timeit.timeit("for i in xrange({}): pass".format(n))
    print n, '\t', t1, '\t', t2
```

Result:

```
n       range           xrange
1       0.566222990493  0.418698436395
2       0.594136874362  0.477882061758
3       0.630704800817  0.488603362929
5       0.725149288913  0.540597548519
10      0.90297752809   0.687031507818
50      2.44493085566   1.89102105759
100     4.31189321914   3.33713522433
```

Comment: that's cool. eh, your results are show, that at least condition(1 element) list still slowly then iterator. but, why create an yield context even more fast then create an list ? and, what's memory cost?

Comment: @Dreampuf: As glglgl's answer shows, first making the generator, then making a list of that, is slightly slower than making a list from the start. However, that is such a small difference that caring about it is premature optimization. And premature optimization is the root of all evil. **In short: If you are unsure, use a generator.**

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with the length of the iterator you are generating, but with how you need to use it afterwards. If you only need to use it once then you should definitely go for **yield**, if you'll go on an use it multiple times you can skip **yield** and just get a regular list. Keep in mind generators you get using yield can only be iterated **once**.

Answer (score 3):

Although your question and its title is still kind of mixed up, I'll try to answer it the way I understand.

If you only want to iterate over the result of `(x)range()`, a `xrange()` (special object) is better than a `range()` (list) for shorter as well as longer ranges:

```
$ python -m timeit 'a=range(3)' 'for i in a: pass'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.608 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'a=xrange(3)' 'for i in a: pass'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.466 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit 'a=xrange(30000)' 'for i in a: pass'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'a=range(30000)' 'for i in a: pass'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 msec per loop
```

So it will be better to use `xrange()` always.

---

If you have a look at the general case, it might be slightly different: you compare "pre-producing" values/objects, storing them in a list and processing them afterwards with consuming them directly after production:

```
def gen(num):
    import random
    i = 0
    while i < num:
        value = random.random()
        yield value
        i += 1

def process(value): pass

def test1(num):
    data = list(gen(num))
    for i in data: process(num)

def test2(num):
    for i in gen(num): process(num)
```

Here it depends how production and consumption can interact, and how big the overhead is.

If you want them to act independently, you can do 'both at once' with threading:

```
def list_eater(l):
    while l:
        yield l.pop(0)
def test3(num):
    data = []
    def producer():
        for i in gen(num): data.append(i)
    import threading
    consumerthread = threading.Thread(target=producer)
    consumerthread.start()
    while data or consumerthread.isAlive():
        for item in list_eater(data): process(item)
        # Optimizeable. Does idle waiting; a threading.Condition might be quite useful here...
```

runs the production and consumes all items as they are here no atter ho long it needs them to be produced or consumed.

Comment: I think (but I could be wrong) that he is not only is asking about range(), but about lists vs generators in general. That's how I understand him at least.

Comment: @LennartRegebro It is hard to tell from the question, that's right.

Comment: sorry for my expression, @LennartRegebro +1

Comment: @glglgl Are you sure that `list(a)` if `a` is a list won't get some kind of special optimisation? I've benchmarked iteration with `for x in (x)range(n): pass` and `xrange` was faster even for n=1, see my post

Comment: Substitute `set(a)` for `list(a)` and `xrange` gets faster too.

Comment: @Kos I have swapped `list(a)` with `tuple(a)` and get the same results, so I think it is true. I think using the `xrange()` object is more expensive than a `list`, so that for small sizes, the cost of creating the list are lower. OTOH, I get the same result with a `for` loop... very strange.

Comment: If I use `max()`, a function which iterates over but doesn't produce a lengthy result, `xrange()` wins for small sizes as well, but with other values than the `for` loop. Very strange. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: xrange is faster than range (see Kos answer) and 12 bytes smaller than an empty list, so it's not more expensive. But making first a generator, return that and then generating a list out of that is more work than making the list directly, which is the difference you see, I think.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Of course - I got mixed up by my own edit, sorry - it's corrected now...

Answer (score 2):

Using `yield` or a generator is mostly irrelevant to the list size, for example:

- if you don't need to process the whole list and could break shortly, it's more efficient to use a generator,.
- to simulate a stream with infinite size, for example a prime number generator.

If however, you have limited memory, an embedded system for example, and can't create the whole list at once then it becomes necessary to use a generator.

As for the cost, there's an additional cost to using a generator, if you count the cost of evaluating the call to the generator each time it's called, but using a list will take more memory, so you can not say generally that a generator is better than a list, since it involves some trade off between memory and performance, whether to use a generator or not depends on your needs and the situation.

Comment: Although everything is correct, you simply do not address the question, nor the mistakes in the askers question, code and assumptions.

Comment: @LennartRegebro I disagree, obviously the OP doesn't know when `yield` should be used.

Comment: No, he asks at what size of the list yield becomes useful. You don't answer that. The correct answer is "1". :-) Your answers are also not so much when they are useful, but when they are necessary.

Comment: @LennartRegebro the size of the list is irrelevant if it's a stream. seems you're missing the point too.

Comment: @LennartRegebro again I disagree, second point is useful not necessary.

Comment: It's not only irrelevant when it is a stream. Still, the point is that a question is asked, and you do not answer it. hence: Downvote. It is really not that hard to understand that point.

Comment: @LennartRegebro the question was "what list size makes yield more useful", the answer explains when yield is useful and that it depends on the situation, I fail to see how that doesn't answer the question, and also fail to understand why you think "1" is the answer. anyway.

Comment: I've now tried for several minutes to formulate a response, but it's hard. You see his question. clearly, you understand it since you are able to reformulate it correctly. You also clearly think the question is valid (which I don't, really) and you clearly do not answer or address the question in your answer. Yet you say "I fail to see how that doesn't answer the question", which is astonishing to me. I don't understand how you can fail to see that.

Comment: Last try: "the answer explains when yield is useful and that it depends on the situation" Yes it does. But the question is not "when is yield useful". The question is "at what size is yield better than a list". You do not answer that. If you still don't understand what I'm saying, lets chat.

Comment: @LennartRegebro how about now, does it address the question more explicitly ?

Comment: That's better. Although I would claim it's not really correct. It's not sometimes irrelevant, it is almost always irrelevant.

Comment: Although perhaps Mux does not answer the OP question, he does give a useful answer. "Mostly irrelevant to the list size" states in clear enough language that the original question was the wrong question to ask and then gives the proper design considerations to make an informed choice. As the Stones sung: "you might find/you get what you need".

Answer (score 2):

Please note that it is not possible to use both `yield` and `return`. A function can be either a generator function or a normal function, but not both.

Usually `yield` avoids having to create an intermediate list, but instead yields elements one by one. This can be useful for instance when you are recursively walking a tree. See this link for an example: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/105873-walk-a-directory-tree-using-a-generator/

Another use of a generator would be when you want to return numerous elements, but your user is probably interested in the first few only (e.g. for search results).

Avoiding the intermediate list will save memory, but only if the caller does not need to create a list out of the results. In general the advantage is that it will allow you to code your generator function more consisely.

Comment: It's not my downvote (in fact, I can't see a downvote at all) but the answer has become outdated since he now removed the yield statement from the question.